# Broadcast large (GBs) variable in Spark hitting Integer.MAX_VALUE. Alternatives?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I'm writing a Spark program that performs an all to all operation on a dataset. I zippedWithIndex my dataset and generated and RDD with the cartesian product of the indices (0..N) so that it holds every possible combination pair. I then collected and broadcast the dataset to be used as a lookup table and perform the operations on the cartesian pairs RDD. It works beautifully and really fast.

The problem is that, even if I have enough memory to hold a large dataset in each node, whenever it's over a couple of GB I get an Exception when broadcasting it saying that the size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Is there any way to configure Spark to allow me to do such a broadcast?

Doing a cartesian product directly on the whole dataset is out of the table since it would amount to an unmanageable RDD. Maybe a join is the way to go, but two of them would be needed and I can't think of a partitioning scheme that would help with it. It will probably be as or more costly as the cartesian product.

Is there a possibility that I am missing?

**EDIT:**

The data set consists of MLLib LabeledPoints. The cartesian product of a GB dataset with millions of points by itself would result in a humongous amount of data, which makes it unfeasible. The lookup table approach I described is much more memory (and time) efficient.

Comment: Broadcasting the entire dataset seems wrong to me - are you sure this is necessary? What sort of all-to-all operation do you need to perform? Can you tell us a little bit more about the actual problem you need to solve? I suspect it can be solved without performing an all-to-all operation.

Comment: I need to compute the distance between every point in a set, so I really need to operate on every possible pairing.

Comment: I agree with @GlennieHellesSindholt , Broadcasting the entire is wrong!

Comment: I see your point, but I think it would be the best alternative of it fits in the nodes memory. Anyway, since the broadcasting mechanism isn't allowing me to do that, I'm looking for alternatives.

Comment: So, what's the format of your input? Can you not use the build-in cartesian function?

Comment: The data set consists of MLLib LabeledPoints. The cartesian product of a GB dataset with millions of points by itself would result in a humongous amount of data, which makes it unfeasible. The lookup table approach I described is much more memory (and time) efficient.

Comment: You can for example serialize lookup table, transfer to each worker and read locally. If operation you perform is a lookup then a proper join could a good alternative. Finally you can use a database for lookups.

Comment: @eirasf - How did you solve the problem? I'm faced with the same thing.

Comment: @dimson Unfortunately I could find any way around it and I had to rearrange my data in a different way.